# Зависимость максимального значения от значения другого инпута

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть два `<input type="number" min="1" max="9">`. Как сделать так, чтобы значение атрибута max для второго инпута равнялось текущему `val()` первого инпута?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$("#num1").on("change", function(){ 
  $("#num2").attr("max", $(this).val()); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="num1" min="1" max="9">
<input type="number" id="num2" min="1" max="9">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#1").focusout(function() {
  $("#2").attr("max", $(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
input 1:
<input id="1" type="number" min="1" max="9">
<br>input 2:
<input id="2" type="number" min="1" max="">
```